# Use same IP for Ingress loadBalancer and postgres service

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

im a beginer on Kube and im trying to connect 2 different frontend (with different DNS name)
and a postgres database on my Kube cluster.

Exemple :
Front 1 = test1.mysite.com
Front 2 = test2.mysite.com

Both dns -> 162.145.23.123

I want my postgres Service to be on the same IP

Front 1

```yaml
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: front-app
  labels:
    app: front-app
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: front-app
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: front-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: front-app
        image: nginx
        ports:
          - containerPort: 80
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: front-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: front-app
  ports:
  # Default port used by the image
  - port: 80
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: demo-localhost
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: test1.mysite.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: front-service
                port:
                  number: 80
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
      - ip: 162.145.23.123
```

Front 2

```yaml
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: front-app2
  labels:
    app: front-app2
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: front-app2
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: front-app2
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: front-app2
        image: nginx
        ports:
          - containerPort: 80
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: front-service2
spec:
  selector:
    app: front-app2
  ports:
  # Default port used by the image
  - port: 80
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: demo-localhost2
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: test2.mysite.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: front-service2
                port:
                  number: 80
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
      - ip: 162.145.23.123
```

Postgres

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hello-pg
  labels:
    app: hello-pg
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 5432
    targetPort: 5432
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: hello-pg
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: db-secret-credentials
  labels:
    app: postgresdb
data:
  POSTGRES_DB: testDB
  POSTGRES_USER: testUser
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: testPassword
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hello-pg-deployment
  labels:
    app: hello-pg
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello-pg
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello-pg
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hello-pg
        image: postgres
        ports:
          - containerPort: 5432
        envFrom:
          - configMapRef:
              name: db-secret-credentials
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Base on your ingress annotations I can see that you are using `ingress nginx` controller. So if you would like to expose your database via the same load balancer as your applications you need to add additional `ConfigMap` object with `TCP` traffic routing configuration and modify your existing `Service` that provision `LB`.

You can find more information about such configuration in [ingress nginx documentation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services/).